# Create and print a tic-tac-toe board

Tags: java, formatting, tic-tac-toe

> Write a program by creating an array of 9 integers that represent the
>   positions in the tic-tac-toe board. Once the array is created, assign
>   values to the board and print the contents of the board out. The
>   values for the board are:
>
> - Board Value: `X`, Integer in Array: `10`
> - Board Value: `O`, Integer in Array: `100`
> - Board Value: Empty, Integer in Array: `0`
>
> This is an example of an array that represents a board:
>
> ```
> [10|0|0|100|0|10|10|100|0]
> ```
>
> Here is what the above array would look like when printed to the screen:
>
> ```
> +---+---+---+
> | X |   |   |
> +---+---+---+
> | O |   | X |
> +---+---+---+
> | X | O |   |
> +---+---+---+
> ```

And I basically solved the problem:

```
public class problem5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = new int[9];
        a[0] = a[5] = a[6] = 10;
        a[3] = a[7] = 100;
        a[1] = a[2] = a[4] = a[8] = 0;
        String[] b = new String[9];
        int x = 0;

        while (x < a.length) {
            if (a[x] == 10)
                b[x] = "X";
            else if (a[x] == 100)
                b[x] = "O";
            else if (a[x] == 0)
                b[x] = " ";
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[0] + " | " + b[1] + " | " + b[2] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[3] + " | " + b[4] + " | " + b[5] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[6] + " | " + b[7] + " | " + b[8] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");

    }
}
```

But  out of curiosity and just for educational purposes, I was wondering if there was a more advanced/shorter way of solving this problem? And by shorter I meant writing a smaller code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need array `b`.  Try this.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        for (int j = i; j < i + 3; ++j)
            System.out.printf("| %s ", a[j] == 10 ? "O" : a[j] == 100 ? "X" : " ");
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
```

Comment: I'd also use String.format to improve readability

Comment: what does the operand '%s' and '?' mean?

Comment: @YRn See [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), and [The ? : operator in Java](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/43.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `for each` loop and `switch` statement to avoid nested IFs.

```
public class problem5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = { 10, 0, 0, 100, 0, 10, 10, 100, 0 };
        String[] b = new String[9];
        int x = 0;

        for (int number : numbers) {
            switch (number) {
            case 10:
                b[x] = "X";
                break;
            case 100:
                b[x] = "O";
                break;
            case 0:
                b[x] = " ";
                break;
            }
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[0] + " | " + b[1] + " | " + b[2] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[3] + " | " + b[4] + " | " + b[5] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
        System.out.println("| " + b[6] + " | " + b[7] + " | " + b[8] + " |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+");

    }
}
```